# How do I combine two XElements with linq select?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to combine two lists of XElements into one :

```
var list1 = XElement.Parse(@"<root><Element name=""foo"">
                                        <ChildElement name=""childFoo"">
                                            <SubChildElement name=""subChildFoo"" />
                                        </ChildElement>
                                    </Element>
                                    <Element name=""bar"">
                                        <ChildElement name=""childBar"">
                                            <SubChildElement name=""subChildBar"" />
                                        </ChildElement>
                                    </Element>
                                    <Element name=""zoo"" /></root>").XPathSelectElements("Element").ToList();

var list2 = XElement.Parse(@"<root><Element name=""foo"" attr=""fooAtr"" />
                                    <Element name=""bar"" attr=""barAtr"" />
                                    <Element name=""zoo"" attr=""barAtr"" /></root>").XPathSelectElements("Element").ToList();

var res = from e2 in list2
           join e1 in list1
           on e2.Attribute("name").Value equals e1.Attribute("name").Value
           select new XElement(e1.Add(e2.Element("ChildElement")));
```

The code won't compile because the select is wrong (XElement.Add() returns void).

How can I combine the two XElements : e1 and e2 inside the select and return the new xelement (e2 with the subelement from e1)

I want to obtain a list in this format :

```
<Element name="foo" attr="fooAtr">
    <ChildElement name="childFoo">
        <SubChildElement name="subChildFoo" />
    </ChildEelement>
</Element>
<Element name="bar" attr="barAtr">
    <ChildElement name="childBar">
        <SubChildElement name="subChildBar" />
    </ChildEelement>
</Element>
<Element name="zoo" attr="barAtr" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would ditch the XPath and use the LINQ to XML query methods to find your elements.  Your `select` needs to copy the name and attributes from the second element and the child elements from the first:

```
var results = from e2 in second.Descendants("Element")
              join e1 in first.Descendants("Element")
                  on (string)e2.Attribute("name") equals (string)e1.Attribute("name")
              select new XElement(e2.Name, e2.Attributes(), e1.Elements());
```

See a working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/J3mcXu

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, works great because I can group the attributes from both e1 and e2 and still use the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting an error is that a `Select()` operation must return an object.  You are essentially attempting to perform a foreach inside of a Select() operation, which is not what it's used.  LINQ does not include a foreach op because it can have side effects, so instead you should use another method.

**EDIT:**  What I originally posted would concatenate the lists instead of merge them.  I was going to post another answer, but @Charles Mager posted the simplest solution to what you're attempting to do.  I'm leaving this answer here though to explain *why* your attempted select statement did not work properly.

Comment: This will just concatenate all the elements together - what's wanted is the merged output shown in the question.